# Problems with jquery keybinding delays on iframes?

Tags: jquery, iframe, key-bindings

I have an application that has an iframed wysiwyg editor of sorts I've built. The iframe content comes off the same domain so its not a XSS issue, but things have to be iframed to keep stylesheets and contents sandboxed.

Anyway, the problem I'm running into is that I have certain hotkeys I want to add to the iframe. For example, hitting "Delete" deletes an object. Hitting control+z undoes the latest action. Pretty basic stuff. I've got all of my actions setup and then work great save for the first x amount of time the iframe loads up. Sometimes I can click and use the keyboard shortcuts right away. Other times I have to click around for 5-10 seconds or edit something before shortcuts come on. Once they start working, they work great, but we need them to work off the bat every time. The script that this runs off of is loaded up in the iframed content. The script passes validation and works in every other way it should.

I've basically found it's a problem with the DOM being confused which document it should be taking its keybinding queues from, but haven't come up with any solutions that work consistently.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- Changing out the selectors from $(document) to $(parent.document) : this had the opposite effect - worked well to start then stopped working.
- Having both document and parent.document as selectors : same erratic behavior
- Binding to $(window) instead of $(document) : same erratic behavior
- Moving the keybindings to a function that gets called after a delay : no luck here
- Calling a function to trigger a click or focus on the iframe body to see if that would kickstart jquery : no luck here either.
- Playing around with the binding function (currently set to .keydown()) - switched to .on('keydown', .keypress, etc. with no luck

This seems to be happening in all browsers, but I've seen it for sure in Chrome and FF latest versions.

I can post some basic examples of my code if you need it, but the code works fine, I think I'm either binding to the wrong thing or there's something else that could be catching this that I'm missing. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out a solution. Each browser needed something a little different to make it work correctly. The issue was completely that the iframe document was not the top one in the DOM, but as soon as you focused on the iframe, the problem went away. Here's what I did for each browser:

- Chrome:

  ```
  $(parent.document).find("#iframe").focus();
  ```
- Firefox: add focus to documentElement and change the trigger selector from $(document) to

  ```
    $(document.documentElement).keydown().focus()
  ```
- IE:

  ```
  $('body').focus();
  ```

Hope that helps someone else.